# Extracting pdf attachment from IMAP account -- python 3.5.2

Tags: python, email, imap

Ok, so I'm trying to save pdf attachments sent to a specific account to a specific network folder but I'm stuck at the attachment part.  I've got the following code to pull in the unseen messages, but I'm not sure how to get the "parts" to stay intact. I think I can maybe figure this out if I can figure out how to keep the email message complete.  I never make it past "Made it to walk" output. All testing emails in this account include pdf attachments. Thanks in advance.

```
import imaplib
import email
import regex
import re

user = 'some_user'
password = 'gimmeAllyerMoney'

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mail.itsstillmonday.com', '993')
server.login(user, password)
server.select('inbox')

msg_ids=[]
resp, messages = server.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
for message in messages[0].split():
        typ, data = server.fetch(message, '(RFC822)')
        msg= email.message_from_string(str(data[0][1]))
        #looking for 'Content-Type: application/pdf
        for part in msg.walk():
                print("Made it to walk")
                if part.is_multipart():
                        print("made it to multipart")
                if part.get_content_maintype() ==  'application/pdf':
                        print("made it to content")
```

Comment: Are these messages multipart messages?  The `maintype` would be just `application` for something with `Content-type: application/pdf`

Comment: @tripleee `Content-Type: multipart` appears in the message header. I will make the update for the application/pdf piece, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use part.get_content_type() to get the full content type and part.get_payload() to get the payload as follows:

```
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/pdf':
        # When decode=True, get_payload will return None if part.is_multipart()
        # and the decoded content otherwise.
        payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)

        # Default filename can be passed as an argument to get_filename()
        filename = part.get_filename()

        # Save the file.
        if payload and filename:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(payload)
```

Note that as tripleee pointed out, for a part with content type "application/pdf" you have:

```
>>> part.get_content_type()
"application/pdf"
>>> part.get_content_maintype()
"application"
>>> part.get_content_subtype()
"pdf"
```

Comment: can I run a message into parts without turning it into a string?  I think that might be where my problem is: `for message in messages[0].split():
        typ, data = server.fetch(message, '(RFC822)')
        msg= email.message_from_string(str(data[0][1]))`  Should I be doing something else before walking the message?

Comment: Maybe you should use email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1]) to parse the messages, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739739/str-object-has-no-attribute-message-from-bytes.